# how to solve list is not callable error in python?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I am new to python and I am trying to sort a dictionary according to the values
what i wrote:

```
         sorted_dictionary = sorted(dictionary.items(),                                                   
          key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
```

surprisingly this worked fine when I first ran the program but then when i rerun my program it did not worked, it gave me the following error:'list' object is not callable

Comment: Can you please define what dictionary and operator values are?

Comment: @HeninRK dictionary={"math":10,"science":5,"english":20}

Comment: I am able to get the desired output using Python 2.7.10

Comment: Somewhere along the line did you assign a value to `sorted`... that is `sorted = somevalue`. Just above this statement you could do `print(sorted)` to see if its still a function.

Comment: with python 3.5 it's working. Please provide the full traceback and are you sure it happens during ``sorted``? I think it's probably an operation you do afterwards.

Comment: ... I should mention that if you create a variable called `sorted` it masks the function formerly known as `sorted`.

Comment: @tdelaney it turned out that i did assign a value for sorted thank you but the problem now is that i deleted this assignment and i rerun my program but this variable is still available how can i delete it?

Comment: How are you rerunning it? If you are typing stuff into the python interpreter, you'll have to exit and start again. if you are rerunning the script, then the old variable assignments are gone... there has to be some other place where its overwritten.

Comment: @tdelaney i am actually using the ide spider so i am just rerunning it

Comment: Hmmm..., are you importing a module you wrote that defines `sorted`? `from somemodule import *` (and `somemodule` has `sorted`) would do it. Not sure how I can help otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
import operator

dictionary = {'math':10, 'science':5, 'english':20}

sorted_dictionary = sorted(dictionary.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

print "Printing the key value pairs of dictionary after sorting on values of a dictionary {0}".format(sorted_dictionary)
print "Sorting the dictionary based on only the values: {0}".format(sorted(dictionary.values()))
```

Output --->

Printing the key value pairs of dictionary after sorting on values of a dictionary:[('english', 20), ('math', 10), ('science', 5)]

Sorting the dictionary based on only the values: [5, 10, 20]

Comment: Are you just saying you can't reproduce the error? That would just be a comment not an answer.

Comment: @tdelaney - Yes I am not able to reproduce the error. The code snippet seems to be working fine

Comment: @Sara Hamad - Were you able to achieve what you wanted to?